# Finding gas to be used by a transaction

Tags: gas, gas-limit

Is there a way to find the total gas that will be used by the transaction before a tx actually takes place?

Does the gas used depend on the amount of tx size in kb?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/197/20451

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to estimate the gas consumption using web3. 
For transactions involving contract functions execution you can use this:

`myContract.methods.myMethod([param1[, param2[, ...]]]).estimateGas(options[, callback])`, [see here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) for more information.

For simple ether transactions you can use:

`web3.eth.estimateGas({from: address, to: address, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})`

See this [discussion](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21510/estimating-gas-cost-of-a-transaction-function-with-web3) for more information

Answer (score 0):

At least Metamask has some functionality to estimate the gas usage, but it's not perfect. More info about that: [What is the general cause for out-of-gas with MetaMask?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45357/what-is-the-general-cause-for-out-of-gas-with-metamask/45358#45358)

The amount of gas required depends on what you are trying to do. There is no "kb" size of transactions as such - the gas requirements are calculated differently. If you are just sending some Ether around, 21000 is default and it's fine. If you are creating a contract, it takes a lot more gas. Some ideas about contract gas requirements: [How to minimize gas consumption during contract creation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10157/how-to-minimize-gas-consumption-during-contract-creation)